# How do I change one of the parameters in script

Tags: javascript, dojo

One of the parameters in the script tag may change dynamically - 
djConfig="parseOnLoad:true, **locale**:'fr-fr'

*Script tag:*

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="dojo-release-1.6.1/dojo/dojo.js"
        djConfig="parseOnLoad:true, locale:'fr-fr' />
```

*where locale may be either fr-fr or en-us,...*

How do I create the script tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest explicitly creating the djConfig object before including the dojo core (as outlined in their docs):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentLocale;

    if([Your Logic Here])
    {
        currentLocale = 'en-us';
    }
    else
    {
        currentLocale = 'fr-fr';
    }

    var djConfig = {
        parseOnLoad: true,
        isDebug: true,
        locale: currentLocale,
        extraLocale: ['ja-jp']
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.4.2/dojo/dojo.xd.js">
</script>
```

Please check out the [dojo docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/djConfig.html) on the subject.

**NOTE:** You should never use self-closing script tags.